# Pivotal Cloud foundry - Spring Boot Actuator not working with Pivotal Apps Manager

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, cloud-foundry

I'm currently deploying a spring boot 1.5.1 application to pivotal cloud foundry.  The Apps manager is displaying the Spring icon but i cant configure the log level or see any of the settings.  I'm getting a browser 'mix content exception'.  Apps manager is trying to access  /cloudfoundryapplication/info over http instead of https and the browser is blocking the request. Is there a setting to force Apps manager to only use https?

Answer (score 0):

Our team encountered a similar issue. We feel it has nothing to do with the apps manager but rather as to how our app behaves.

In our case we had a bad configuration which was causing the URLS getting built as http when httpRequest.getScheme() was being called.

```
server.tomcat.internal-proxies: <ips other then your proxy>
```

Correcting this property in our case by letting it to default as defined [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java#L272#L278) let the getScheme to be returned as https and there by when the call being made to /cloudfoundryapplication/info the scheme got built as https.

Also another suggestion made by one of our colleague which also resolves this issue but would not address the root cause is - fronting your application(highest precedence) with [ForwardedHeaderFilter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.java)  - this causes the X-FORWARDED-* headers to be available in your httpServletResquest as described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.java#L49#L53)